# When trying to create a new asset volume, I don't have the form line where to put the path

Tags: assets

As per the question, see the included screenshot:

[image: No URL line]

I just don't have the URL form to type where the volume should be on the server.

Comment: That's... odd. Are there any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: Yes, there is:

`<script>new Craft.HandleGenerator('#name', '#handle');

Craft.cp.setJobInfo([], false);

new Vue({

    el: "#url\u002Dcontainer",


    data() {

                var data = ;

        data.inputProps.onInputChange = this.onInputChange;

                return data;

    },`


This line  `var data = ;` is flagged with an " unexpected token  ';' " error. The function " new " is flagged as " anonymous function " at line 576.

Comment: Huh... could be that's a bug.  Any chance you want to send some CP/SSH creds over to support@craftcms.com so we can look into it?

Comment: Yep, doing that right now.

Comment: Answer to the problem (sorry, forgot to post here): the problem wasn't from the server not Craft, but my ISP's modem. I still don't know why caused the issue, besides the fact the reboot of the modem fixed it and that the issue was caused by the modem itself. So if you encounter the same issue than me, try to reboot the modem.